# How to delete items from an array that have an index that is a multiple of N

Tags: java, arrays

i have a simple code that creates an array from user input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int NumOfValues = in.nextInt();

    int [] array = new int[NumOfValues];
}
```

Now I want to take all the indexes that are a multiple of n and delete them. for ex: `array[n]`, `array[2n]` and so on. All help is appreciated.

Comment: What _values that are multiple of n_? You have just created an array, not filled it with values. `array[2n]` would cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException.` (assuming `n` is equal to `NumOfValues`.. What is `n`?)

Comment: Could i get an explanation on the down vote please? For future improvements

Comment: It would help us understand what you are trying to do, perhaps, if you showed what you've already tried and how it did not work.

Comment: @danielp I didn't down vote but here are a couple of things you might consider. The statement 'I want to take all values that are a multiple of n' implies you want to filter based on the values in the array. But your examples of `array[n]` and `array[2n]` implies you want to filter on the indices of the array. This makes your question ambiguous. You also having formatted your code correctly (the variables are not indented) and you haven't listed a few things you've already tried.

Comment: I do want to filter them by their indexes.

Comment: @danielp Yes I understand that - I was trying to suggest improvements as you requested. Perhaps a better subject line would have been "How to delete items from an array that have an index that is a multiple of N"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean remove entries that are multiples of n or indices that are multiples of n?

If the former and you can use Java 8 then this is trivial to do using streams:

```
array = Arrays.stream(array)
    .filter(i -> i % n != 0)
    .toArray();
```

If you are not familiar with streams then this statement says: convert my array to a stream of integers, filter it for only those ones which aren't multiples of n (i.e. modulo n is not zero) then collect the stream in a new array.

If the latter (i.e. remove every nth item) then you can still use streams but it's a bit more obscure:

```
array = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .filter (i -> i % n != 0)
    .map(i -> array[i])
    .toArray();
```

This essentially produces a stream of integers representing the indices, filters them, maps to the corresponding item of the array and the converts back to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not complete. Your code needs at least one function (probably `main()`). Also, you should move the given variables into this function (at least most of them). And before you ask about deleting values, you should first show how you fill your array